# Java Callstack with recursion. How to get last Object back?

Tags: java, oop, recursion, callstack

I want to make a simulator where you can enter rooms and then leave them. If you leave you are in the room before you entered. I want to do it with recursion and call stack. It works good if I go into a new room, but I can't go back. Any solutions for this ?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hausaufgabe10Aufgabe01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Room workingroom = new Room("Arbeitszimmer", false);
        Room bedroom = new Room("Schlafzimmer", false);
        Kitchen kitchen = new Kitchen("Kueche", false, false);
        Bathroom bathroom = new Bathroom("Badezimmer", false, false);
        Room hall = new Room("Flur", false);
        hall.setNeighborRooms(bathroom, kitchen, bedroom, workingroom);
        workingroom.setNeighborRooms(bedroom);
        bedroom.setNeighborRooms(workingroom);
        Flat myFlat = new Flat(bathroom, kitchen, bedroom, workingroom, hall);
        boolean inFlat = false;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        walkThrough(myFlat, hall, input);
    }

    public static void walkThrough(Flat myFlat, Room myRoom, Scanner input) {
        while (true) {

            System.out.println("\nSie sind im: " + myRoom.getName());
            System.out.println("Was wollen sie tun ? ");

            System.out.println("1) Lichtsschalter bestätigen ? ");
            System.out.println("2) Raum verlassen? ");
            System.out.println("3) Nachbar Raum betreten ? ");

            int intMax = 3;
            if (myRoom.getName().equals("Kueche")) {
                System.out.println("4) Herd betätigen ? ");
                intMax = 4;
            }
            if (myRoom.getName().equals("Badezimmer")) {
                System.out.println("4) Dusche betätigen ? ");
                intMax = 4;
            }

            
            boolean shouldIReturn = false;
            int choosenNumber = input.nextInt();
            switch (choosenNumber) {

            case 1:
                myRoom.useLight();
                break;
            case 2:
                shouldIReturn = true;
                break;
            case 3:
                if (myRoom.getNeighborRooms() != null) {
                    myRoom = chooseRoom(input, myRoom);
                    walkThrough(myFlat, myRoom, input);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Keine Nachbarraum vorhanden");
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (intMax == 4) {
                    myRoom.useSpecial();
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("\nGeben sie eine richtige Eingabe ein!!");
                if(intMax < 4) {
                    System.out.println("1 - 3 \n");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("1 - 4 \n");
                }
                break;
            }
            
            if (shouldIReturn) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public static Room chooseRoom(Scanner input, Room myRoom) {
        if (myRoom.getNeighborRooms().length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < myRoom.getNeighborRooms().length; ++i) {
                System.out.println((i + 1) + ") "
                        + myRoom.getNeighborRooms()[i].getName());
            }
            int choosenRoom = input.nextInt() - 1;
            return myRoom.getNeighborRooms()[choosenRoom];
        }
        return myRoom.getNeighborRooms()[0];
    }
}
```

I tried to return so I end the current function and went back to the one before, but I do not get the name of the room I was in before. How can I get the object I was before ?

Answer (score 0):

Make `myRoom` final and see what compile time error you get.

Think about what was happening before, and you'll realise why you didn't get the original room name when you printed `System.out.println("\nSie sind im: " + myRoom.getName());`.

In the line `myRoom = chooseRoom(input, myRoom);` you are setting `myRoom` to a new value. So you don't have the old value when you return from `chooseRoom`.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The final local variable myRoom cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment

Comment: See some more hints in my answer

Comment: i dont get it why. i tried to get it with the getStack method but i dont know why i don get the old name after i return. could you tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

my fault was that i overwrite the old referenz here:

```html
case 3:
                if (myRoom.getNeighborRooms() != null) {
                    Room newRoom = chooseRoom(input, myRoom);
                    walkThrough(myFlat, newRoom, input);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Keine Nachbarraum vorhanden");
                }
                break;
```

i needed to make a new variable for the recursion if i dont it will overwrite the old one

Comment: at Room newRoom = chooseRoom(input, myRoom);
i used the old room myRoom so ive overwritten it and i cant get the old one